# str_replace not working when text together

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

This might be a noob question but when I do

```
str_replace("<P id=description>", "", $content);
```

this is part of the `$content <P id=description>ஈழ` but I cannot get rid of this, and I get the same problem when i try to replace the `ம்</P>` using `str_replace("</P>", " ", $content);` but it works when the `</P>` has space in between, and when I try `preg_match_all "'<(.*?)>'si";` i dont get those tags.

Comment: Show us your actual code please.

Comment: what do u mean by acutal code?

Comment: the actual code that you are running so that we can see the context and get an idea of what might be wrong here.

Comment: so basically i am trying to strip all the html tags and this is the content = <P id=eow-description>ஈழத்தில் , இதயத்தில் இரத்தம் அவர்கள்  ஆவணப்படம்</P>

Comment: see my answer below for a possible solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with multibyte strings you might want to use functions that are for multibyte strings, like [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

strings has to match!

```
$content = '<P id=eow-description>ஈழ';
str_replace("<P id=eow-description>", "", $content);
```

will work...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments use [`strip_tags()` (linked)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all the HTML from the document.

Comment: I tried this it removes most tags but it doesnt remove the ones I have mentioned.

Comment: Looks that is a problem with multibyte strings as @Molecule mentioned in their answer.